# Is there a way for Eclipse to generate a tree showing the import statements of a java class, recursively?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a number of .java files with a number of import statements. I'd like to have Eclipse generate a tree or other view that shows for every file which other files are linked through import statements.

I've tried to google this, and most of what it gives concerns generating the AWT tree view that eclipse internally uses. Is there a view or plugin I can use to generate this import statement tree?

Comment: That's not what import is for.  I think you want Maven dependency trees.  Import isn't about class usage or loading.  It's about saving you keystrokes, nothing more.

Comment: There's a misconception in your question. Importing a symbol from a different package is only loosely coupled with using that symbol. E.g. people write `import java.util.*;` (by the way, not a good idea) and don't use all classes from that package, or they use both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` and can't import both because of the name collision.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are focusing on the *wrong* thing here. You see, import statements are mainly for human readers. You are much more concerned about the **real** dependencies of your classes. Who cares if a user *imported* class X? What you need to know is that you depend on X, and maybe also on Z, because X depends on Z.

In other words: don't spend your time parsing import statements. Use a tool such as [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html) in order to find out about the *real* dependencies that your classes have! Because, as said: you also need the transitive dependencies of your classes. And import statements tell you *zero* about these!

Given the comments by the OP: when we are really talking about "small scale", as in "I have 5 classes I want the dependencies for" then I suggest a not very nice, but efficient solution: simply remove these "other" classes. Turn to the file system, and move the classes "you depend on away". Refresh in eclipse, and make sure the errors panel gives you **all** errors in your project/workspace. Then start fixing them.

In other words:

- when dealing with a "large" problem, then analyse class file dependencies
- when working a "small" thing, then don't overthink - simply remove your dependencies and see what happens.

Comment: Is jdeps something that can help me figure out how certain code depends (indirectly) on other parts of the codebase? The problem I have is that I have about 5-10 Java files in Eclipse, and I wish to figure out how they are dependent on another part of the code so I can remove those dependencies. Most of these dependencies are through constants which are easily dealt with, but it's other stuff I want to figure out.